# pytest is running the testcases even I specify to collect only testcases using --collect-only

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I have an environment where I need to test the command line scripts using pexpect. I have written the test cases and I am using pytest to automate the test case execution. My `pytest.ini` file looks like this

```
[pytest]
python_files=check_*.py
python_functions=test
```

Content of `check_host.py` is

```
import pytest,pretest
def pre_test():
    assert(pretest.pre_test() == "Pretest successfull")
```

When I run `py.test --collect-only`, the test case is run instead of just displaying the list of test cases to be run.

Then problem I am facing is if I run `py.test -v check_host.py` the test case `pre_test` is run twice; once while collecting and again in the actual run.

Comment: Perhaps `pre_test` is a specific hook for py.test? What happens if you change its name?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it isn't. @Java05461 Does importing `pretest` do this maybe?